# How to get Jenkins repository server to host only stable builds?

Tags: maven, svn, jenkins, jenkins-pipeline

I have Jenkins version 2.7.1 running on a Windows 7 machine. It is successfully pulling code from a subversion repository and running tests.  I have the test jobs set up for the development branch of each project only.

We periodically make stable releases of the projects in jar files with version numbers. I would like to have Jenkins be the repository manager for those stable releases.  These are made by hand - There is no Jenkins job making or testing stable releases.  The projects do use Maven.

Each stable build is tagged in the subversion repository, so it could be made again on demand if needed.

I downloaded the [Maven repository server](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Jenkins+Maven+Repository+Server) hoping to make this fit the purpose. I read the documentation that's provided, but it's pretty terse.  As I understand it and have it configured now, this appears to have a couple of issues:

- If I go to `jenkins-ip/plugin/repository/project`, it has made directories there that expose the names of all of my projects, which seems undesirable. (Here `jenkins-ip` is the IP where I access Jenkins on my local network.)
- On the other hand, there's nothing but empty directories under these projects, so they're currently useless.
- These projects all correspond to the continuous testing of the development branch.  There's no apparent way to get the stable builds into the hierarchy. (It doesn't seem efficient to create a job for each stable release...)

Is there anyway to get Jenkins (with this plugin or through another method) to be the repository manager just for the stable builds?  I know that I can start a different repository manager like archiva, but it would be ideal to use Jenkins since it's already running and it seems to claim capability for this function now.

Answer (score 0):

To use Maven repository server you have to build the project on Jenkins.
Then the plugin will expose all archived artifacts as maven repo.

Note you need to use a "Maven project" type for it to work (freestyle is not supported)

There are several plugins that will help you manage building from multiple tags, however not all of them work with "Maven project" type.

You could also try [Jenkins pipeline](https://jenkins.io/doc/pipeline/) (previously "Workflow") or the [Job-DSL plugin](https://jenkinsci.github.io/job-dsl-plugin/).

A simplest solution would be to have a build parameter specify the tag name (then checkout e.g. `^/tags/projectname/${tagParam}`), but you have to figure out how to trigger the job then.